# PHP: display messages which hide after refreshing page in php

Tags: php

I want to display a message when a user register and hide it when a user refreshes the webpage.

Comment: Well, then include a message in the output after registration, and don't include one otherwise. If you need a more precise answer, amend your question with the precise scenario - how exactly does your registration work? Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: So what have you tried, where's your code?

Comment: If you are showing message on successful query execution it would automatically hide the message on page refreshing remember refreshing some time will reexecute your querydedepending on how you are taking care of page refresh

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['seen'])){
    echo 'A message';
}
$_SESSION['seen'] = true;
?>
```

Comment: +1, best method. If the message were to show on post, attempting to refresh would also resend the post data. If the message were shown because of a get variable, then it would hide on refresh.

Comment: You could always do a header redirect to the message page to avoid the resend.